# Asyncio: cancelling tasks and starting new ones when a signal flag is raised

Tags: python, python-asyncio

My program is supposed to read data forever from provider classes stored in `PROVIDERS`, defined in the config. Every second, it should check whether the config has changed and if so, stop all tasks, reload the config and and create new tasks.

The below code raises `CancelledError` because I'm cancelling my tasks. Should I really try/catch each of those to achieve my goals or is there a better pattern?

```py
async def main(config_file):
    load_config(config_file)

    tasks = []
    config_task = asyncio.create_task(watch_config(config_file))  # checks every 1s if config changed and raises ConfigChangedSignal if so

    tasks.append(config_task)
    for asset_name, provider in PROVIDERS.items():
        task = asyncio.create_task(provider.read_forever())
        tasks.append(task)

    try:
        await asyncio.gather(*tasks, return_exceptions=False)
    except ConfigChangedSignal:
        # Restarting
        for task in asyncio.tasks.all_tasks():
            task.cancel()  # raises CancelledError
        await main(config_file)


try:
    asyncio.run(main(config_file))
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    logger.debug("Ctrl-C pressed. Aborting")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are on Python 3.11, your pattern maps directly to using `asyncio.TaskGroup`, the "successor" to `asyncio.gather`, which makes use of the new  "exception Groups". By default, if any task in the group raises an exception, all tasks in the group are cancelled:

I played around this snippet in the ipython console, and had run `asyncio.run(main(False))` for no exception and `asyncio.run(main(True))` for inducing an exception just to check the results:

```
import asyncio

async def doit(i, n, cancel=False):
    await asyncio.sleep(n)
    if cancel:
        raise RuntimeError()
    print(i, "done")

async def main(cancel):
  try:
      async with asyncio.TaskGroup() as group:
          tasks = [group.create_task(doit(i, 2)) for i in range(10)]
          group.create_task(doit(42, 1, cancel=cancel))
          group.create_task(doit(11, .5))
  except Exception:
      pass
  await asyncio.sleep(3)
```

Your code can acommodate that -
Apart from the best practice for cancelling tasks, though, you are doing a recursive call to your `main` that, although will work for most practical purposes, can make seasoned developers go "sigh" - and also can break in edgecases, (it will fail after ~1000 cycles, for example), and leak resources.

The correct way to do that is assembling a while loop, since Python function calls, even tail calls, won't clean up the resources in the calling scope:

```
import asyncio
...


async def main(config_file):
    while True:
        load_config(config_file)
        try:
            async with asyncio.TaskGroup() as tasks:
                tasks.create_task(watch_config(config_file))  # checks every 1s if config changed and raises ConfigChangedSignal if so

                for asset_name, provider in PROVIDERS.items():
                tasks.create_task.create_task(provider.read_forever())

            # all tasks are awaited at the end of the with block
        except *ConfigChangedSignal:  # <- the new syntax in Python 3.11
            # Restarting is just a matter of re-doing the while-loop
            # ... log.info("config changed")
            pass

        # any other exception won't be caught and will error, allowing one
        # to review what went wrong
        
...
```

For Python 3.10, looping over the tasks and cancelling each seems alright, but you should look at that recursive call. If you don't want a while-loop inside your current main, refactor the code so that main itself is called from an outter while-loop

```
async def main(config_file):
    while True:
        await inner_main(config_file)

async def inner_main(config_file):
    load_config(config_file)

    # keep the existing body
    ...
    except ConfigChangedSignal:
        # Restarting
        for task in asyncio.tasks.all_tasks():
            task.cancel()  # raises CancelledError
       # await main call dropped from here
```

Comment: I ended up pretty much doing exactly what you suggest in your second answer, and I had indeed forgotten that Python doesn't like recursion, so a while True loop solved it. My initial confusion as to how to tackle this came from thinking that `KeyboardInterrupt` and `CancelledError` inherit from `Exception` and they both don't. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

jsbueno’s answer is appropriate.

An easy alternative is to enclose the entire event loop in an outer “while”:

```
async def main(config_file):
    load_config(config_file)

    tasks = []
    for asset_name, provider in PROVIDERS.items():
        task = asyncio.create_task(provider.read_forever())
        tasks.append(task)

    try:
        await watch_config(config_file)
    except ConfigChangedSignal:
        pass

try:
    while True:
        asyncio.run(main(config_file))
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    logger.debug("Ctrl-C pressed. Aborting")
```

Comment: I think this will have the unfortunate side effect of double-creating the tasks every time the config is changed

Comment: It’s not apparent, but by the time asyncio.run() returns, it has cancelled all the pending tasks and closed the loop. So the tasks should not be double-created.

Comment: ah you are correct. This is also a valid solution, however I prefer the one above as it is more transparent about what's going on.